# jQuery DOMWindow script doesn't release memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, memory-management

I'm attempting to use a jQuery script I've found on
http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html
on my website to create a lightbox/domwindow popup when a visitor clicks a link.

Unfortunately, it appears the script isn't releasing memory when the user closes the dom window. If the user opens and closes the window several times, it causes the page to slow down dramatically and crash the user's browser.

Here is the jQuery script from the above website:

```
(function($){

    //closeDOMWindow
    $.fn.closeDOMWindow = function(settings){

        if(!settings){settings={};}

        var run = function(passingThis){

            if(settings.anchoredClassName){
                var $anchorClassName = $('.'+settings.anchoredClassName);
                $anchorClassName.fadeOut('fast',function(){
                    if($.fn.draggable){
                        $anchorClassName.draggable('destory').trigger("unload").remove();   
                    }else{
                        $anchorClassName.trigger("unload").remove();
                    }
                });
                if(settings.functionCallOnClose) {
                    settings.functionCallAfterClose();
                }
            }else{
                var $DOMWindowOverlay = $('#DOMWindowOverlay');
                var $DOMWindow = $('#DOMWindow');
                $DOMWindowOverlay.fadeOut('fast',function(){
                    $DOMWindowOverlay.trigger('unload').unbind().remove();                                                                    
                });
                $DOMWindow.fadeOut('fast',function(){
                    if($.fn.draggable){
                        $DOMWindow.draggable("destroy").trigger("unload").remove();
                    }else{
                        $DOMWindow.trigger("unload").remove();
                    }
                });

                $(window).unbind('scroll.DOMWindow');
                $(window).unbind('resize.DOMWindow');

                if($.fn.openDOMWindow.isIE6){$('#DOMWindowIE6FixIframe').remove();}
                if(settings.functionCallOnClose){settings.functionCallAfterClose();}
            }   
        };

        if(settings.eventType){//if used with $().
            return this.each(function(index){
                $(this).bind(settings.eventType, function(){
                    run(this);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        }else{//else called as $.function
            run();
        }

    };

    //allow for public call, pass settings
    $.closeDOMWindow = function(s){$.fn.closeDOMWindow(s);};

    //openDOMWindow
    $.fn.openDOMWindow = function(instanceSettings){    

        var shortcut =  $.fn.openDOMWindow;

        //default settings combined with callerSettings////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        shortcut.defaultsSettings = {
            anchoredClassName:'',
            anchoredSelector:'',
            borderColor:'#ccc',
            borderSize:'4',
            draggable:0,
            eventType:null, //click, blur, change, dblclick, error, focus, load, mousedown, mouseout, mouseup etc...
            fixedWindowY:100,
            functionCallOnOpen:null,
            functionCallOnClose:null,
            height:500,
            loader:0,
            loaderHeight:0,
            loaderImagePath:'',
            loaderWidth:0,
            modal:0,
            overlay:1,
            overlayColor:'#000',
            overlayOpacity:'85',
            positionLeft:0,
            positionTop:0,
            positionType:'centered', // centered, anchored, absolute, fixed
            width:500, 
            windowBGColor:'#fff',
            windowBGImage:null, // http path
            windowHTTPType:'get',
            windowPadding:10,
            windowSource:'inline', //inline, ajax, iframe
            windowSourceID:'',
            windowSourceURL:'',
            windowSourceAttrURL:'href'
        };

        var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.openDOMWindow.defaultsSettings , instanceSettings || {});

        //Public functions

        shortcut.viewPortHeight = function(){ return self.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;};
        shortcut.viewPortWidth = function(){ return self.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;};
        shortcut.scrollOffsetHeight = function(){ return self.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;};
        shortcut.scrollOffsetWidth = function(){ return self.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft;};
        shortcut.isIE6 = typeof document.body.style.maxHeight === "undefined";

        //Private Functions/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        var sizeOverlay = function(){
            var $DOMWindowOverlay = $('#DOMWindowOverlay');
            if(shortcut.isIE6){//if IE 6
                var overlayViewportHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop - 4;
                var overlayViewportWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth - 21;
                $DOMWindowOverlay.css({'height':overlayViewportHeight +'px','width':overlayViewportWidth+'px'});
            }else{//else Firefox, safari, opera, IE 7+
                $DOMWindowOverlay.css({'height':'100%','width':'100%','position':'fixed'});
            }   
        };

        var sizeIE6Iframe = function(){
            var overlayViewportHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop - 4;
            var overlayViewportWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth - 21;
            $('#DOMWindowIE6FixIframe').css({'height':overlayViewportHeight +'px','width':overlayViewportWidth+'px'});
        };

        var centerDOMWindow = function() {
            var $DOMWindow = $('#DOMWindow');
            if(settings.height + 50 > shortcut.viewPortHeight()){//added 50 to be safe
                $DOMWindow.css('left',Math.round(shortcut.viewPortWidth()/2) + shortcut.scrollOffsetWidth() - Math.round(($DOMWindow.outerWidth())/2));
            }else{
                $DOMWindow.css('left',Math.round(shortcut.viewPortWidth()/2) + shortcut.scrollOffsetWidth() - Math.round(($DOMWindow.outerWidth())/2));
                $DOMWindow.css('top',Math.round(shortcut.viewPortHeight()/2) + shortcut.scrollOffsetHeight() - Math.round(($DOMWindow.outerHeight())/2));
            }
        };

        var centerLoader = function() {
            var $DOMWindowLoader = $('#DOMWindowLoader');
            if(shortcut.isIE6){//if IE 6
                $DOMWindowLoader.css({'left':Math.round(shortcut.viewPortWidth()/2) + shortcut.scrollOffsetWidth() - Math.round(($DOMWindowLoader.innerWidth())/2),'position':'absolute'});
                $DOMWindowLoader.css({'top':Math.round(shortcut.viewPortHeight()/2) + shortcut.scrollOffsetHeight() - Math.round(($DOMWindowLoader.innerHeight())/2),'position':'absolute'});
            }else{
                $DOMWindowLoader.css({'left':'50%','top':'50%','position':'fixed'});
            }

        };

        var fixedDOMWindow = function(){
            var $DOMWindow = $('#DOMWindow');
            $DOMWindow.css('left', settings.positionLeft + shortcut.scrollOffsetWidth());
            $DOMWindow.css('top', + settings.positionTop + shortcut.scrollOffsetHeight());
        };

        var showDOMWindow = function(instance){
            if(arguments[0]){
                $('.'+instance+' #DOMWindowLoader').remove();
                $('.'+instance+' #DOMWindowContent').fadeIn('fast',function(){if(settings.functionCallOnOpen){settings.functionCallOnOpen();}});
                $('.'+instance+ '.closeDOMWindow').click(function(){
                    $.closeDOMWindow(); 
                    return false;
                });
            }else{
                $('#DOMWindowLoader').remove();
                $('#DOMWindow').fadeIn('fast',function(){if(settings.functionCallOnOpen){settings.functionCallOnOpen();}});
                $('#DOMWindow .closeDOMWindow').click(function(){                       
                    $.closeDOMWindow();
                    return false;
                });
            }

        };

        var urlQueryToObject = function(s){
              var query = {};
              s.replace(/b([^&=]*)=([^&=]*)b/g, function (m, a, d) {
                if (typeof query[a] != 'undefined') {
                  query[a] += ',' + d;
                } else {
                  query[a] = d;
                }
              });
              return query;
        };

        //Run Routine ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var run = function(passingThis){

            //get values from element clicked, or assume its passed as an option
            settings.windowSourceID = $(passingThis).attr('href') || settings.windowSourceID;
            settings.windowSourceURL = $(passingThis).attr(settings.windowSourceAttrURL) || settings.windowSourceURL;
            settings.windowBGImage = settings.windowBGImage ? 'background-image:url('+settings.windowBGImage+')' : '';
            var urlOnly, urlQueryObject;

            if(settings.positionType == 'anchored'){//anchored DOM window

                var anchoredPositions = $(settings.anchoredSelector).position();
                var anchoredPositionX = anchoredPositions.left + settings.positionLeft;
                var anchoredPositionY = anchoredPositions.top + settings.positionTop;

                $('body').append('<div class="'+settings.anchoredClassName+'" style="'+settings.windowBGImage+';background-repeat:no-repeat;padding:'+settings.windowPadding+'px;overflow:auto;position:absolute;top:'+anchoredPositionY+'px;left:'+anchoredPositionX+'px;height:'+settings.height+'px;width:'+settings.width+'px;background-color:'+settings.windowBGColor+';border:'+settings.borderSize+'px solid '+settings.borderColor+';z-index:10001"><div id="DOMWindowContent" style="display:none"></div></div>');        
                //loader
                if(settings.loader && settings.loaderImagePath !== ''){
                    $('.'+settings.anchoredClassName).append('<div id="DOMWindowLoader" style="width:'+settings.loaderWidth+'px;height:'+settings.loaderHeight+'px;"><img src="'+settings.loaderImagePath+'" /></div>');

                }

                if($.fn.draggable){
                    if(settings.draggable){$('.' + settings.anchoredClassName).draggable({cursor:'move'});}
                }

                switch(settings.windowSource){
                    case 'inline'://////////////////////////////// inline //////////////////////////////////////////
                        $('.' + settings.anchoredClassName+" #DOMWindowContent").append($(settings.windowSourceID).children());
                        $('.' + settings.anchoredClassName).unload(function(){// move elements back when you're finished
                            $('.' + settings.windowSourceID).append( $('.' + settings.anchoredClassName+" #DOMWindowContent").children());              
                        });
                        showDOMWindow(settings.anchoredClassName);
                    break;
                    case 'iframe'://////////////////////////////// iframe //////////////////////////////////////////
                        $('.' + settings.anchoredClassName+" #DOMWindowContent").append('<iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" wspace="0" src="'+settings.windowSourceURL+'" name="DOMWindowIframe'+Math.round(Math.random()*1000)+'" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:none;background-color:#fff;" class="'+settings.anchoredClassName+'Iframe" ></iframe>');
                        $('.'+settings.anchoredClassName+'Iframe').load(showDOMWindow(settings.anchoredClassName));
                    break;
                    case 'ajax'://////////////////////////////// ajax //////////////////////////////////////////    
                        if(settings.windowHTTPType == 'post'){

                            if(settings.windowSourceURL.indexOf("?") !== -1){//has a query string
                                urlOnly = settings.windowSourceURL.substr(0, settings.windowSourceURL.indexOf("?"));
                                urlQueryObject = urlQueryToObject(settings.windowSourceURL);
                            }else{
                                urlOnly = settings.windowSourceURL;
                                urlQueryObject = {};
                            }
                            $('.' + settings.anchoredClassName+" #DOMWindowContent").load(urlOnly,urlQueryObject,function(){
                                showDOMWindow(settings.anchoredClassName);
                            });
                        }else{
                            if(settings.windowSourceURL.indexOf("?") == -1){ //no query string, so add one
                                settings.windowSourceURL += '?';
                            }
                            $('.' + settings.anchoredClassName+" #DOMWindowContent").load(
                                settings.windowSourceURL + '&random=' + (new Date().getTime()),function(){
                                showDOMWindow(settings.anchoredClassName);
                            });
                        }
                    break;
                }

            }else{//centered, fixed, absolute DOM window

                //overlay & modal
                if(settings.overlay){
                    $('body').append('<div id="DOMWindowOverlay" style="z-index:10000;display:none;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background-color:'+settings.overlayColor+';filter:alpha(opacity='+settings.overlayOpacity+');-moz-opacity: 0.'+settings.overlayOpacity+';opacity: 0.'+settings.overlayOpacity+';"></div>');
                    if(shortcut.isIE6){//if IE 6
                        $('body').append('<iframe id="DOMWindowIE6FixIframe"  src="blank.html"  style="width:100%;height:100%;z-index:9999;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);"></iframe>');
                        sizeIE6Iframe();
                    }
                    sizeOverlay();
                    var $DOMWindowOverlay = $('#DOMWindowOverlay');
                    $DOMWindowOverlay.fadeIn('fast');
                    if(!settings.modal){$DOMWindowOverlay.click(function(){$.closeDOMWindow();});}
                }

                //loader
                if(settings.loader && settings.loaderImagePath !== ''){
                    $('body').append('<div id="DOMWindowLoader" style="z-index:10002;width:'+settings.loaderWidth+'px;height:'+settings.loaderHeight+'px;"><img src="'+settings.loaderImagePath+'" /></div>');
                    centerLoader();
                }

                //add DOMwindow
                $('body').append('<div id="DOMWindow" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;'+settings.windowBGImage+';overflow:auto;padding:'+settings.windowPadding+'px;display:none;height:'+settings.height+'px;width:'+settings.width+'px;background-color:'+settings.windowBGColor+';border:'+settings.borderSize+'px solid '+settings.borderColor+'; position:absolute;z-index:10001"></div>');

                var $DOMWindow = $('#DOMWindow');
                //centered, absolute, or fixed
                switch(settings.positionType){
                    case 'centered':
                        centerDOMWindow();
                        if(settings.height + 50 > shortcut.viewPortHeight()){//added 50 to be safe
                            $DOMWindow.css('top', (settings.fixedWindowY + shortcut.scrollOffsetHeight()) + 'px');
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'absolute':
                        $DOMWindow.css({'top':(settings.positionTop+shortcut.scrollOffsetHeight())+'px','left':(settings.positionLeft+shortcut.scrollOffsetWidth())+'px'});
                        if($.fn.draggable){
                            if(settings.draggable){$DOMWindow.draggable({cursor:'move'});}
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'fixed':
                        fixedDOMWindow();
                    break;
                    case 'anchoredSingleWindow':
                        var anchoredPositions = $(settings.anchoredSelector).position();
                        var anchoredPositionX = anchoredPositions.left + settings.positionLeft;
                        var anchoredPositionY = anchoredPositions.top + settings.positionTop;
                        $DOMWindow.css({'top':anchoredPositionY + 'px','left':anchoredPositionX+'px'});

                    break;
                }

                $(window).bind('scroll.DOMWindow',function(){
                    if(settings.overlay){sizeOverlay();}
                    if(shortcut.isIE6){sizeIE6Iframe();}
                    if(settings.positionType == 'centered'){centerDOMWindow();}
                    if(settings.positionType == 'fixed'){fixedDOMWindow();}
                });

                $(window).bind('resize.DOMWindow',function(){
                    if(shortcut.isIE6){sizeIE6Iframe();}
                    if(settings.overlay){sizeOverlay();}
                    if(settings.positionType == 'centered'){centerDOMWindow();}
                });

                switch(settings.windowSource){
                    case 'inline'://////////////////////////////// inline //////////////////////////////////////////
                        $DOMWindow.append($(settings.windowSourceID).children());
                        $DOMWindow.unload(function(){// move elements back when you're finished
                            $(settings.windowSourceID).append($DOMWindow.children());               
                        });
                        showDOMWindow();
                    break;
                    case 'iframe'://////////////////////////////// iframe //////////////////////////////////////////
                        $DOMWindow.append('<iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" wspace="0" src="'+settings.windowSourceURL+'" name="DOMWindowIframe'+Math.round(Math.random()*1000)+'" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:none;background-color:#fff;" id="DOMWindowIframe" ></iframe>');
                        $('#DOMWindowIframe').load(showDOMWindow());
                    break;
                    case 'ajax'://////////////////////////////// ajax //////////////////////////////////////////
                        if(settings.windowHTTPType == 'post'){

                            if(settings.windowSourceURL.indexOf("?") !== -1){//has a query string
                                urlOnly = settings.windowSourceURL.substr(0, settings.windowSourceURL.indexOf("?"));
                                urlQueryObject = urlQueryToObject(settings.windowSourceURL);
                            }else{
                                urlOnly = settings.windowSourceURL;
                                urlQueryObject = {};
                            }
                            $DOMWindow.load(urlOnly,urlQueryObject,function(){
                                showDOMWindow();
                            });
                        }else{
                            if(settings.windowSourceURL.indexOf("?") == -1){ //no query string, so add one
                                settings.windowSourceURL += '?';
                            }
                            $DOMWindow.load(
                                settings.windowSourceURL + '&random=' + (new Date().getTime()),function(){
                                showDOMWindow();
                            });
                        }
                    break;
                }

            }//end if anchored, or absolute, fixed, centered

        };//end run()

        if(settings.eventType){//if used with $().
            return this.each(function(index){                 
                $(this).bind(settings.eventType,function(){
                    run(this);
                    return false;
                });
            }); 
        }else{//else called as $.function
            run();
        }

    };//end function openDOMWindow

    //allow for public call, pass settings
    $.openDOMWindow = function(s){$.fn.openDOMWindow(s);};

})(jQuery);
```

And here is the hyperlink tag from my HTML that opens up the light box.

```
<a href="/php/ajax/edit_map_pin.htm?mAddressBox0=FALSE&mPin_ID=foo" class="AjaxDOMWindow">Change Icon</a>
```

Here is a screenshot from siege detailing the memory step increase every time the user opens and closes the DOM window from that link. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: did you find a workaround by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that remove() removes nodes from the document-tree, but they still are available(for example you can use them again and put them back to the document).

In MSIE you can set the outerHTML-property of nodes to an empty string to really delete them, in other browsers I'm not sure how. You may have a look at this: http://www.josh-davis.org/node/7 .

The author uses there the delete-statement, but I'm not sure if it really deletes the nodes.

Comment: Thanks @Dr. Molle, do you have any idea where i might modify my script to delete the nodes when I close the DOMWindow?

Comment: Or is there any way to specify that when the DOMWindow is reopened it should recycle a node rather than create one?